# Eclipse Luna and JBoss server 5.2.0

Tags: eclipse, jboss5.x

I have Eclipse Luna installed and trying to add JBoss server 5.2.0. But in server adaptors I only till 5.1 is visible after 6.1 is present. Let me know how to add jboss 5.2.0.

Comment: Have you tried treating it as you would 5.1? They are probably very similar from tooling perspective.